# Connect to Codespace: Get codespace request failed with status 499. Correlation ID: undefined

Tags: codespaces, github-codespaces

When I try to create codespaces for this repo: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research.

VS Code - GitHub Codespaces (Extension) v1.9.1 popup an error:

```
Connect to Codespace: Get codespace request failed with status 499. Correlation ID: undefined
```